# How to build Python PEX using Bazel?

Tags: python, bazel, pex

I'm trying to build a pex_binary in mac OS X for my Apache Heron application (written in Python), but it fails with error.

### Details of bazel build error below.

```
$bazel build pmTop
ERROR: /Arun/Python/Heron/PatMon/WORKSPACE:1:1: name 'git_repository' is not defined
ERROR: Error evaluating WORKSPACE file
ERROR: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'pex/pex_rules.bzl': no such package '@io_bazel_rules_pex//pex': error loading package 'external': Could not load //external package
ERROR: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'pex/pex_rules.bzl': no such package '@io_bazel_rules_pex//pex': error loading package 'external': Could not load //external package
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.104s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
```

### Contents of my WORKSPACE below.

```
git_repository(
    name = "io_bazel_rules_pex",
    remote = "https://github.com/benley/bazel_rules_pex.git",
    tag = "0.3.0",
)

load("@io_bazel_rules_pex//pex:pex_rules.bzl", "pex_repositories")
pex_repositories()
```

### Bazel version details below.

```
$bazel version
Build label: 0.25.0
Build target: bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Wed May 1 21:47:49 2019 (1556747269)
Build timestamp: 1556747269
Build timestamp as int: 1556747269
```

Not sure, why it's unable to fetch the pex_rules.bzl package. I'm not behind firewall. Appreciate any pointers to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `git_repository` rule is not known. Add the following statement on the top of your `WORKSPACE` file

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "git_repository")
```